# Custom field in PHP file

Tags: php, get-post

im a beginner with PHP, so i hope that someone can help me solving this issue.

I want to display the expiration date of a post with the following plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-schedule-posts/

I've think i can use:
`$hasp_expire_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, ‘hasp_expire_date’, true );`

But i don't know how to insert it into a php file. I need to place in this code (Where it says CODE HERE):

```
                $num_comments = get_comments_number( $block_data['id'] );
                $entry_comments = 'CODE HERE<i class="fa fa-speech-bubble"></i><span>'.$num_comments.' '._nx( 'Comment', 'Comments', $num_comments, 'comments', 'uncode' ).'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `$hasp_expire_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, ‘hasp_expire_date’, true );` is giving you the correct value you need, you are storing your that in the `$hasp_expire_date` variable.

So edit that second line to:

```
$num_comments = get_comments_number( $block_data['id'] );

// Pull in the value you need
$hasp_expire_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, ‘hasp_expire_date’, true );

// You are going to concatenate or add that value to your string.
$entry_comments = $hasp_expire_date.'<i class="fa fa-speech-bubble"></i><span>'.$num_comments.' '._nx( 'Comment', 'Comments', $num_comments, 'comments', 'uncode' ).'</span>';
```

Hope that helps!!